# Multiple Buttons React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-navigation, alert

My goal is to create a page for a specific user homepage with buttons to direct them to their accessible pages. I am in the testing phase right now and I want to use alerts to see if the button will react to being clicked on. However, as being new to React, I am having trouble have multiple buttons return an alert message in my browser. This is what I have so far.

```
// Here will be the mentor page with a decent layout and buttons to future pages.
import React from 'react';
import '../Mentor/Button.css'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


function Mentor() {

  function sayHello() {
    alert('Hello');
  }

  function createQuiz(){
      alert('You clicked me to create a quiz!');
  }



return (
<div>
    <button onClick={sayHello}>
      Click me!
    </button>

    <button onCLick={createQuiz}>
      Create Quiz
    </button>
  </div> 
  );
}
  
export default Mentor;
```

For not to get any errors, I added  but it will only give me a message from sayHello and not from createQuiz. And the navigate import is something I am planning on using later when problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you copy pasted your code here, it looks like you simply misspelled the second *onClick* ! You wrote *onC**L**ick* instead of *onC**l**ick*.